# Generating a Random Number in C

Tags: c, random, numbers

If i want to generate **DIFFERENT** random numbers in C between 0 and 1,000,000, would the following suffice?

```
srand(time(NULL));
int k = (rand() % 1000000;
```

from the output i'm seeing, only about 32767 different random numbers are being generated!

Thanks!

Comment: How can you see the output?  `int k = (rand() % 1000000;` wouldn't even compile.

Comment: size of integer reaches max at 32767

Comment: @devnull i'm using a loop

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy I think you might be correct. However, i tried it with a long int and the same happens!

Comment: Standard C `rand` is really crappy. You might want to search the internet for a better library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have pointed out that `RAND_MAX` is 32767 in your implementation. But how do you get higher random numbers?

If you want to get random numbers that exceed `RAND_MAX`, you have to roll the dice twice, in your example:

```
x = (rand() % 1000) * 1000 + rand();
```

Answer (score 2):

> rand int rand (void); Generate random number Returns a pseudo-random
>   integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX.
>
> **RAND_MAX** Maximum value returned by rand This macro expands to an
>   integral constant expression whose value is the maximum value returned
>   by the rand function.
>
> This value **is library-dependent, but is guaranteed to be at least
>   32767 on any standard library implementation.**

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to generate such a large number of random numbers then?

Comment: you could use library or write your own generator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Answer (score 1):

`rand` generates random numbers in the range [0..`RAND_MAX`], and in some C libraries (notably the one from MSVC), `RAND_MAX` is as small as 32767. It's also a very weak RNG on MSVC, so you may want to look at better random number libraries, e.g. [randomkit](http://js2007.free.fr/code/index.html#RandomKit), or whatever non-standard functions your library offers.

Comment: @user3126802: no, it's hardwired into the `rand` implementation.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to generate such a large number of random numbers then?

Answer (score 0):

The manual for `rand()` says:

> The rand() function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to `RAND_MAX` inclusive (i.e., the mathematical range [0, `RAND_MAX`]).

It seems your particular implementation uses a `RAND_MAX` of 0xFFFF (or 32767).

You need to either switch libraries, investigate if there's any configurability in the library you have, or use a different random-number implementation (not your C library's).

Answer (score 0):

How you showing your output? Also with simple code you can achieve this like

```
long int x;
while(1)
{
   x=random(1000000);
   printf ("%ld\n",x)
}
```

Also if you library support upto that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing problems with int types, try with double values. 
drand48() returns a number within the interval [0.0, 1.0) so you can multiply it by 1000000 and then round it to obtain what you want:

```
int k = floor(drand48() * 1000000);
```

Do not forget to initialize with srand48() instead of srand()

Answer (score -1):

```
int k = (rand() % 1000000);
```

You are collecting the output in an integer(when int is 2 bytes) which has the maximum capacity to hold 32767.

Also RAND_MAX is the Maximum value returned by rand which is 32767.

Comment: That is extremely unlikely on modern hardware.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is _at least_ 32767. It's 2147483647 on my machine, for example.